# Wiring AC motors in parallel

Tags: motor, ac

I am having some Somfy motorized curtains installed in my home, but I struggle to understand the following statement in the manual:

[image: Somfy System Wiring]

*Wiring multiple Sonesse 40 WT's in parallel will result in damage to the motor.*

Why would this be the case? Even if I didn't wire them directly at the motor end, wouldn't they still end up in a parallel configuration elsewhere in my installation?

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. Perhaps there has been an error in translation. I would look for other literature about those or similar motors.

Comment: I certainly don't understand it. But I don't see how they could mistranslate the picture as well.

Comment: damage possibly occurs when one of the motors reaches its endstop, but power remains applied so that the second motor keeps moving

Comment: @jsotola: Hm.. That actually makes some sense. At least if they are not in complete sync. They do get too warm and shut off if I leave the power on for too long.

Comment: They could be using the tiny delay from the relay or intelligent behavior of the controller to prevent the starting currents from being simultaneous too.  Entirely speculation, but if they start at the exact same time and didn't have enough torque to get moving fast enough they may overheat.

Comment: But turning them on with relay contacts in parallel would not be significantly different that wiring them in parallel. You cannot COUNT on any perceived delay from one contact to another, the relay mfrs strive hard to AVOID that.